# How to extract this XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, extract

I want to extract a xml file (XML_DATA):

The XML:

```
-<XP6>
 +<INFO_1>
 +<INFO_2>
 +<INFO_3>
 -<Prdct>
  -<Prdct_row>
   .....
   <LILBFLO>Samsung,corp. </LILBFLO> <--value
```

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
EXTRACTVALUE(XML_DATA,'/Prdct/Prdct_row/LILBFLO/text()')
```

How to use `extractvalue` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the +/- symbols indicate collapsed nodes and your XML actually looks something like the sample in this CTE, you just need to include the root node in the path:

```
with your_table (xml_data) as (
  select xmltype('<XP6>
 <INFO_1/>
 <INFO_2/>
 <INFO_3/>
 <Prdct>
  <Prdct_row>
   <LILBFLO>Samsung,corp. </LILBFLO>
  </Prdct_row>
 </Prdct>
</XP6>') from dual
)
select EXTRACTVALUE(XML_DATA,'/XP6/Prdct/Prdct_row/LILBFLO/text()')
from your_table;

EXTRACTVALUE(XML_DATA,'/XP6/PRDCT/PRDCT_ROW/LILBFLO/TEXT()')
------------------------------------------------------------
Samsung,corp.
```

But the `extractvalue()` function is deprecated, so you should use an XMLQuery instead:

```
select XMLQuery('/XP6/Prdct/Prdct_row/LILBFLO/text()' passing XML_DATA returning content)
from your_table;

XMLQUERY('/XP6/PRDCT/PRDCT_ROW/LILBFLO/TEXT()'PASSINGXML_DATARETURNINGCONTENT)  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Samsung,corp.
```